# Referential integrity constraint violation on delete in a manytomany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Getting this exception

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKrtt5rijo65gon4wgqj4pv44hj: PUBLIC.user_order FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.""order""(id) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from "order" where "id"=?
```

with the following setup:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract @Data class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_order",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public @Data class Client extends User {
// just fields
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public @Data class Worker extends User {
// just fields
}
```

```
@Entity
public @Data class Order {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
    @ToString.Exclude @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude // this is due to a lombok specific stackOverFlow 
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I googled this and every problem was due to incorrect set up of the relationship, I've triple checked everything and it looks correct to me, and when I check the generated tables everything is just as I wanted. But still, when I try to delete an order, I get the mentioned exception. Any clues as to why?

I have a data init on context refresh, if that's useful:

```
        Worker workerA = (Worker) new Worker().setSalary(BigDecimal.ZERO).setRole(Role.USER).setName("Kate")
                                              .setLastName("Park").setPassword(encoder.encode("123"))
                                              .setUsername("immkath").setFatherName("Andrii")
                                              .setPhone("+38(066) 207 0746");

        Worker workerB = (Worker) new Worker().setSalary(BigDecimal.TEN).setRole(Role.ADMIN).setName("Dar")
                                              .setLastName("Poz").setPassword(encoder.encode("123"))
                                              .setUsername("dpozinen").setFatherName("Andrii")
                                              .setPhone("+38(050) 385 0660");

        Order orderA = new Order().setPayState(OrderState.NOT_PAYED).setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(12))
                                  .setDueDate(LocalDateTime.of(1999, 2, 3, 12, 22))
                                  .setWorkState(OrderState.QUEUED).setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        Order orderB = new Order().setPayState(OrderState.PAYED).setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(12))
                                  .setDueDate(LocalDateTime.of(1999, 2, 3, 12, 22))
                                  .setWorkState(OrderState.DELAYED).setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());

        workerA.getOrders().add(orderA);
        workerB.getOrders().add(orderB);

        userRepo.save(workerA);
        userRepo.save(workerB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on both ends of the relation. In your case this means that if you try to delete a user it will automatically delete his user_order entries.

If you delete an order however (as you are doing) since it's not cascaded it doesn't have the authority to delete from user_order and in that table you still have entries pointing to the order you are trying to delete.

Either first manually delete all user_order entries in which this order is present and only then delete the order itself or put `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` here `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`